# Python Telnetlib read_until '#' or '>', multiple string determination?

Tags: python, port, automated-tests, telnet, telnetlib

```
if (tn.read_until('>')):
    action1
else:
    action2
```

or

```
if (tn.read_until() == '>'):
    action1
else:
    action2
```

I just want the `read_until()` to check which desired String comes first, and do different actions.
Or is there any equivalent ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_until). Read until wants the *expected* string as a positional argument and an optional timeout. I would do it like this:

```
>>> try:
...     response = tn.read_until(">", timeout=120) #or whatever timeout you choose.
... except EOFError as e:
...     print "Connection closed: %s" % e

>>> if ">" in response:
...    action1
... else:
...    action2
```

If you want multiple different characters you can use `read_some()`

```
>>> while True: #really you should set some sort of a timeout here.
...    r = tn.read_some()
...    if any(x in r for x in ["#", ">"]):
...        break
```

Answer (score 4):

Better yet just use:

```
buff_tpl = tn.expect(["#", ">"])
```

This will return a tuple with three items, the first (index of 0) is the index of the list item matched, the second is and object matched, and the third is the output text.

You can print the buffer output using buff_tpl[2], and know which item matched using buff_tpl[0]