# How to give commands inside telnet session using python

Tags: python-3.x, telnet, telnetlib

I am writing python script to automate some task in simulator... to connect to simulator command is `telnet localhost <port>`.

This command I am giving through `os.system(telnet localhost <port>)`.

It is working.

And simulator is running:

> Trying ::1...
>   Connected to localhost.
>   Escape character is '^]'.
>   >

Now I have to give commands through python inside this but I can't
inside this(>) I have to give..I used telnet commands but it didn't work.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os,re,telnetlib
host = "localhost"
port = "1111"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host, port)
tn.write("exit")
```

This is sample code but it is not working.

Comment: You seem to mention two different ways to open a telnet session, `os.system('telnet localhost <port>')` and `tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host, port)`. The second way seems more idiomatic to me, but you are saying that "it is not working"? Can you explain *how* is it not working?

Comment: after connecting to telnet my simulator will run ...we have to give commands inside this > ....but unable to write using tn.write

Answer (score 2):

Write command needs the content to be provided in bytes. Try this:

```
import os,re,telnetlib

host = "google.com"
port = "80"

telnet_client = telnetlib.Telnet(host, port)
print('Connection established')

telnet_client.write(b'exit')
print('<END/>')
```

Comment: this is used for connecting to a localhost..but i am using telnet localhost 2222 command to run simulator....after this command      Trying ::1... Connected to localhost. Escape character is '^]'. > it has to come like this but i am not getting it

Comment: Have you checked the firewall and the antivirus? Depending on the configuration they can reject connections.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to tell `telnetlib` to [read until](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_until) the prompt and then write the command you want to issue.

```py
import os,re,telnetlib
host = "localhost"
port = "1111"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host, port)
tn.read_until(b">", timeout=10) # <- add this line
# tn.read_until(b"> ", timeout=10) # if prompt has space behind
tn.write(b"exit\n")
```

You might also find this question helpful: [Python Telnetlib read_until '#' or '>', multiple string determination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074909/python-telnetlib-read-until-or-multiple-string-determination)

Comment: i added that line but i am getting error ...............................telnet.read_until('>', timeout=10)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/telnetlib.py", line 302, in read_until
    i = self.cookedq.find(match)
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'

Comment: @lokeswari you're using Python 3, the telnetlib expects bytes or ints which is the error you got. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: i am not getting any errors using this ..but my simulator is not running and unable to give exit command